# Is it possible to modify the hex code of a video file encoded in the VP9 codec to make it play on repeat indefinitely?

Tags: video, hex, codec, webm, vp9

Is it possible to modify the hex code of a video file encoded in the VP9 codec to make it play on repeat indefinitely?

Let me explain:

Certain MP4 files can be set to do strange stuff, one example is shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxHQ7dW6M2s&t):

I was able to replicate this with WEBP files, by changing the value after marker 44 89 in WebM files to FF FF FF FF, which resulted in a wacky video.

Playing that video in a browser, like chrome or opera, results in the timestamp/timecode in the bottom left just counting up, with no end in site.

Is it possible to also do this for a VP9 codec? I was reading documentation on how it works, and though it looks very complicated, I think I could figure it out.

But before I try to do it, I would like to know if it is even possible. Does anyone know if it is possible?

I tried editing the WEBP file marker 44 89 in WebM files to FF FF FF FF, but after uploading to YouTube, it changed to a normal timestamp.

Comment: Personally I've never heard of a `looping = true` flag in the bytes of a VPX codec. If it's not mentioned in their documentation then it won't be possible (_ie:_ media players will ignore an unknown setting or refuse to play the whole file)